# Unity 5.6.0f3 Inspector Tooltips are off in macOS, is me or everyone the same?

Tags: unity, macos

Running latest version (5.6.0f3) in macOS, my tooltips are always misalign to the left of my screen, is me or anyone else also experience the same? And, it is still misalign even after I reset the layout setting to factory default.

Here are the screenshots https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRldI.jpg

---

Update: Filed a bug report.

Comment: File a bug report from within the editor.

Comment: So, you experience this as well?, I want to make sure is not just me mess up my mac

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I've experienced it too.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Fixed in patch release 5.6.0p3 https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases?version=5.6

(884238) - Editor: Fixed screen offsets updates for tooltips.